# How to Use reference table to insert rows into a data frame in R?

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, categorization

I have a data frame (labels) that I would like to use as a reference or lookup table of the form:

```
V1  V2
1   1   WALKING
2   2   WALKING_UPSTAIRS
3   3   WALKING_DOWNSTAIRS
4   4   SITTING
5   5   STANDING
6   6   LAYING
```

The data frame to use the reference table is (test, ncol = 564, nrow = 2947) where the first three colnames are (test_subject, test_label(num 1-6), data_set) where test_label(1-6) equal the strings referenced above.

Could someone help me figure out how I can use my lookup table to insert a new column called "activity_label" and each observation of that column would correspond to the string equivalent of the referenced number from the reference table.

E.g., if test_label row 1 equals 5 then activity_label row 1 would equal "Standing"

Thanks so much for all of your help!

## #

After using the merge method:

```
> test2[1:10, 564: 565]
   angle(Z,gravityMean) activity_label
1            0.04404283        walking
2            0.04134032        walking
3            0.04295217        walking
4            0.03611571        walking
5           -0.09080307        walking
6           -0.08602478        walking
7           -0.07997668        walking
8            0.04372663        walking
9            0.19900166        walking
10           0.20350821        walking
```

### analyzing structure of the remaining dfs

```
> str(test1)
'data.frame':   2947 obs. of  565 variables:
 $ test_labels                         : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ test_subject                        : int  12 12 12 12 4 4 4 12 9 9 ...
 $ observ_set                          : Factor w/ 1 level "test": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ tBodyAcc-mean()-X                   : num  0.228 0.303 0.237 0.306 0.29 ...

> str(train1)
'data.frame':   7352 obs. of  565 variables:
 $ train_labels                        : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ V1                                  : int  27 7 7 26 7 26 6 6 6 7 ...
 $ observ_set                          : Factor w/ 1 level "train": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ tBodyAcc-mean()-X                   : num  0.262 0.354 0.344 0.292 0.314 ...
```

Comment: does your test table already have the activity number (1,2,3,4,5 and 6) against each test subject in it and you just want to create an additional column with the string equivalent of the activity number?

Comment: hi @vagabond, yes, that is correct. The test-df has a column of activity numbers (but no labels) and I just want to insert a column of "strings" whose value is related the "id" key in test-df.

Comment: I reproduced the sample dataset , lookup table and the merge - didn't get any error - see the example in my answer. I think the warning is related to `class` of your variables. paste the output of `str(test)` and `str(lookup_table)`.

Comment: Yeah it looks like the appending function worked alright it was probably annoyed with all of the variables it had to deal with :)

Comment: dundies. thanks for the help. now I just have to bring these two massive dfs together into one dataset. I love this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `ifelse` :

if data frame = test and activity number column = activitynum,

```
test$activitylabel <- ifelse(test$activitynum == 1, "walking, ifelse(test$activitynum == 2, "walking_upstairs", ifelse(test$activitynum == 3, "walking_downstairs", ifelse(test$activitynum == 4, "sitting", ifelse(test$activitynum == 5, "standing", ifelse(test$activitynum == 6, "laying", NA))))))
```

another way is to create a look-up table and then do a `merge` as suggested by @Jaehyeon:

```
lookup <- data.frame(activitynum = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), activity = c("walking", "walking_upstairs", "walking_downstairs", "standing", "sitting", "laying"))

survey <- data.frame(id = c(seq(1:10)), activitynum = floor(runif(10, 1, 7)), var1 = runif(10, 1, 100))

merge(survey, lookup, by = "activitynum", all.x = TRUE)

> str(lookup)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ activitynum: num  1 2 3 4 5 6
 $ activity   : Factor w/ 6 levels "laying","sitting",..: 4 6 5 3 2 1
> str(survey)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ id         : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ activitynum: num  1 2 4 1 4 6 2 4 2 2
 $ var1       : num  52.3 60.5 53.3 49.8 73.1 ...
```

Comment: Hi @vagabond I tried your method and it appears to have worked with a caveat. It threw some warnings(test2): Error in cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append) : 
  argument 2 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat' -- having said that my new column of labels is there.

Comment: Which method did you try ? The `merge` or the `ifelse`? Also, can you paste some sample data? paste the output of: `test[1:10,  1:5]` - I am assuming your activitynum column and id are in the first 5 columns.

Comment: I used the merge method and it appended the new column [565] to the end of the dataset. (see main post for out put)

Answer (score 0):

I'd do as following. Mapping is done by 'test_label' and 'id' and they are merged using `merge()`. If you want to keep all values in `df`, use `all.x = T`. Otherwise remove it.

```
set.seed(1237)
lookup <- data.frame(id = 1:6, activity = LETTERS[1:6])
df <- data.frame(test_label = sample(1:6, 10, replace = T))
merge(df, lookup, by.x = "test_label", by.y ="id", all.x = T)

test_label activity
1           1        A
2           1        A
3           2        B
4           2        B
5           3        C
6           5        E
7           5        E
8           6        F
9           6        F
10          6        F
```